# Development Environment Django port 8000 to serve React (staticfiles)

Tags: reactjs, django, django-staticfiles, django-cors-headers

I'm trying to setup a development environment for React and Django.

https://github.com/axilaris/django-react <-- Here is my project code for reference. You can easily run in with the instructions below easily.

Django (runs on port 8000)

```
cd backend <-- to to this directory
backend> python3 -m venv backendvirtualenv && source backendvirtualenv/bin/activate
backend> pip install -r requirements.txt
backend> python manage.py makemigrations
backend> python manage.py migrate
backend> python manage.py runserver
```

React (runs on port 3000)

```
cd frontend <-- to to this directory
frontend> npm install
frontend> npm run build
frontend> npm start
```

However, I'm trying to serve React staticfiles in Django so that I can run React on localhost:8000.

In settings file:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../frontend/build/static')]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

and the I run

```
backend> python manage.py collectstatic
backend> python manage.py runserver
```

However, when I point to my browser (http://localhost:8000/). It doesnt still have the React pages.

[image: image description]

How can I configure django so that I can run React and Django together in port 8000 ?

Comment: You only have path api/, you need to set path / for matching empty path as home webpage. Or try accessing /api path.

Comment: I would like the react pages to be the default entry /. how can i serve that in localhost:8000 ?

Comment: Try `path('', include('user_api.urls')), `

Comment: You have 4 views. What view you need as /? `path('register', views.UserRegister.as_view(), name='register'),
        path('login', views.UserLogin.as_view(), name='login'),
        path('logout', views.UserLogout.as_view(), name='logout'),
        path('user', views.UserView.as_view(), name='user'),`

Comment: I mean, I understand your problem now. You need to create new django view for react page pointing to /.

Comment: could you provide a full answer. i dont think what you are doing is correct. I have React running on port 3000. now i dont want that, i want it to be accessing the React page in the same port 8000 as django. From what I have seen, its possible through staticfiles to serve it. use_api is for React to communicate with Django. I dont see how you are doing it correctly. I think the staticfiles needs to be copied correctly in the staticfolder and maybe updating the urls.py so that those React path are recognized. But I maybe wrong. I need a proper answer to it. try the github, it should be easy.

Comment: Django is not a static server. You need a view to render react template to / path. That's the only way.

Comment: Given the `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` your react app is at localhost:8000/static/index.html. Change STATIC_URL, or even better, make a TemplateView at /, which imports your js assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for :
https://fractalideas.com/blog/making-react-and-django-play-well-together-hybrid-app-model/

It uses whitenoise and collectstatic

The idea here is that you can build your React app, and once built, HTML is served as template by Django, and Whitenoise is used for the static files (js/css/svg etc)

Answer (score 0):

Follow below procedure in the given order.

- Open console
- run `python manage.py startapp frontend`
- go into `frontend folder` just created by above command and

  - create a file called `urls.py`
  - create a folder called `templates`
  - create a folder called `static`
- add newly created `frontend` app to project settings.py(in installed apps, as normally do) [ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial02/#id3)
- Move/copy your react app folder content to newly created templates folder and static folder
- Open views.py and create index view [ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial01/#id1)  - (Put index.js content in index.html and use django static template tag and put appropriate urls for app.js,app.css, index.css imports.)
- Open urls.py and add index view [ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial01/#id2)
- Open project urls.py and add empty path map to newly created index view [ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial01/#id3)

Django is not a static server. Even if you could host it from static folder in development, in production it(static files) should be handled by CDN or nginx. Not django.

This answer shows how to convert react app to django app.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and verify it. I feel this is the answer somehow. Are there any good examples you have seen somehow ?

Comment: I looked at your code. Put index.js content in index.html and use django static template tag and put appropriate urls for app.js,app.css, index.css imports. I haven't seen any guide. I just made the answer.  Happy coding. If you encounter any problems, please note here. Happy to help.