# Cannot make Django run the frontend from Vite's build ("was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)")

Tags: django, build, static, vite

My frontend is a React app that I compiled using `npm run build`. Once the build folder is copied to the django project, I go in my Django virtualenv and run `python3 manage.py collectstatic` and `python3 manage.py runserver`

When I run the server, I can read two errors in the console:

```
Loading module from “http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/index-sLPpAV_Z.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
The resource from “http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/index-6ReKyqhx.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

and one warning:

```
Loading failed for the module with source “http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/index-sLPpAV_Z.js”.
```

(Django) settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

package.json

```
...
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "rm -rf ../backend/build && tsc && vite build && cp -r build ../backend/build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
...
```

I am confuse because there is no static folder in the build folder. Django gives me this warning:

```
WARNINGS:
?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory '/home/user/project/backend/build/static' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.
```

The build folder looks like this:

```
build/
----assets/
--------index-<randomString>.css
--------index-<anotherString>.js
----index.html
----vite.svg
```

Note: I run everything locally

Comment: Show us your settings.py. Did you add your react app to installed apps?  Look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/78230001/13861187 .